# Geogebra 4th order bezier curve

Tags: geogebra

Please can you tell me how I can draw 4th order bezier curve in Geogebra?

I have these polynomial cubics

```
B0(t) = (1 - t)3,
B1(t) = 3t(1 - t)2,
B2(t) = 3t2(1 - t),
B3(t) = t3
```

but with these I can draw only simple Bezier curve and I need 4th order bezier curve with 5 control points.

Comment: please add additional details

Answer (score 4):

If you have endpoints `A`, `E` and control points `B`, `C`, `D`, you can create the 4th degree Bézier curve using this GeoGebra command:

```
Curve(t⁴ A + 4t³ (1 - t) B + 6t² (1 - t)² C + 4t (1 - t)³ D + (1 - t)⁴ E, t, 0, 1)
```

You can get the polynomials by multiplying the binomial coefficients with corresponding powers of `t` and `(1-t)`, see [explicit definition of Bézier curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Explicit_definition) on Wikipedia for details.